# Configure Universal Access options from the command-line

Tags: command-line, accessibility

What's a general way to control the accessibility options from the command-line? These are usually set from the 'Universal Access' GUI, but I'd like to know if there is a common way to control these settings that does not rely on the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xkbset package is what you want; latchlock doesn't work in 12.04, though.

man page:

http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/xkbset

The author's home page:

http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/software/

Comment: You're welcome--I hope it helps!